# Show nested route component in new page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a nested route component which is getting displayed at the bottom of the parent component. I want to display this component in a new page. Here is my code-

CategoryList.js

```
class CategoryList extends Component {
  state = {
    categories: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/testcategory')
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      }).then(data => {
        this.setState({ categories: data.categories });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error: true });

      });
  }

  categorySelectedHandler = (id) => {
    this.props.history.replace('/testcategory/' + id);

  }

  render() {
    let categories = <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Something went wrong!</p>;
    if (!this.state.error) {
      categories = this.state.categories.map(category => {
        {this.props.children}
        return (
          <Table.Row key={category.id}>

            <Table.Cell>{category.name}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{category.id}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell> <Button icon labelPosition='left' onClick={() => this.categorySelectedHandler(category.id)}>show</Button></Table.Cell>
            {/* Tried this as well
              <Table.Cell>
              <Link to={"/category/"+category.id}>
                <Button icon labelPosition='left' >Show</Button>
              </Link>
            </Table.Cell> */}
          </Table.Row>
        )
      })
    }
return (
      <div>
        <Table stackable>
          <Table.Header>
            <Table.Row >
              <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>ID</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Operations</Table.HeaderCell>
            </Table.Row>
          </Table.Header>
          <Table.Body>
            {categories}
            {this.props.children}
          </Table.Body>

        </Table>
        <Route path={this.props.match.url + '/:id'} exact component={CategoryDetails} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CategoryList;
```

CategoryDetails.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './CategoryDetails.css';
class CategoryDetails extends Component {

  state = { loadedCategory: null }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadData();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.loadData();
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextProps.match.params.id != nextState.loadedCategory.id ;
  }
  loadData=() =>{
    if (this.props.match.params.id) {
      if (!this.state.loadedCategory || (this.state.loadedCategory && this.state.loadedCategory.id !== +this.props.match.params.id)) {
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/testcategory/' + this.props.match.params.id)
          .then(results => {
            return results.json();
          }).then(data => {
            this.setState({ loadedCategory: data});
          })
          .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ error: true });
          });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    let category = <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Please select a Post!</p>;
    if (this.props.match.params.id) {
      category = <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Loading...!</p>;
    }


    if (this.state.loadedCategory) {
      category = (
        <div className="CategoryDetails">
          <h1>{this.state.loadedCategory.name}</h1>
          <p>{this.state.loadedCategory.code}</p>
          <p>{this.state.loadedCategory.id}</p>
          {this.props.children}

        </div>

      );
    }
    return (category);
  }
}

export default CategoryDetails;
```

Comment: Hey Chetan, it sounds like CategoryList and CategoryDetails are actually sibling routes, considering their views are entirely divorced from one another. For React Router 4+, you want to treat routes like they were any other component (and thus that they won't replace any parent elements).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want the `Show` component to appear in another page, can it be done in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `CategoryDetails` Route from CategoryList file and move it to the file where Route specified for `CategoryList`

```
<Route path={this.props.match.url + '/:id'} exact component={CategoryDetails} />

<Route path={this.props.match.url + '/:dummyid'} exact component={CategoryList} />
```

Comment: you probably don't need the dummy ID, but instead should use something like "/categories" for CategoryList and "/categories/:id" for CategoryDetails

Comment: Thanks you @Piyush and @Sam, it worked. I had some problem in `shouldComponentUpdate` life cycle hook which when fixed worked as required.